# In sqoop import : splitz size

Tags: mysql, sqoop

In sqoop import if the primary key id of mysql table has all values from 1 to 10000. An outlier 12000 came in. You are trying to import with a where clause mentioning id < 20000. What is the split size?

Answer (score 0):

Split size will be calculated as min=1 and max=12000 so max-min/no.of.mappers
Here we will not calculate 20000 because the actual highest value in primary key is 12000 12000/4=3000 mapper1 =1-3000 mapper2=3001-6000 mapper3=6001-9000 mapper 4=9001-12000